# Tomcat Startup Server Not Working

Tags: tomcat, failed-installation

I installed tomcat but when I cd into the tomcat directory and run startup.bat I just get the following output below.  Usually tomcat says "INFO: Server startup in 12345 ms" but now it only outputs the paths below and brings me back to the command prompt.

I've checked my classpaths and they are listed below.  What else could be wrong with this?

```
C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\bin>startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\jdk1.6.0_13\jre"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\bin\bootstrap.jar"
C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\bin>
```

Update: after the message above, another cmd opens up quickly and closes and it closes too fast for me to read.  I believe that is the bootstrap.jar.  So the question is why is bootstrap.jar failing?

Comment: What does your log files say?

Comment: It doesn't even produce a log.  My C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\logs is empty

Comment: You could try "catalina.bat run" and see the error(s) if any - the default port could be in use, for instance.

Comment: Open up your conf/logging.properties and try setting the *catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level* to *ALL* and see if any log gets produced on restart?

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem, but in my case CATALINA_HOME looks like  "C:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\" (ends with a back slash). I had removed back slash from CATALINA_HOME and tomcat have became to work.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. For me it was because the Tomcat files I downloaded were the source code files, not the binary dist.